# Eclipse RCP - ScopedPreferenceStore qualifier. How to use the default preference storage?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, default, preferences

In my Eclipse 3.7 RCP Application I was getting the PreferenceStore as following: 
`Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore()` which returns an `IPreferenceStore`.
Here the Activator's own preference storage is used.

Now I would like to use use an Instance of `ScopedPreferenceStore` which is an `IPreferenceStore` either. 
Now the preference storage-node musst be set explicitely, by passing a plugin-id as a qualifier parameter in the constructor `ScopedPreferenceStore(IScopeContext context, String qualifier)`.

**Example:** 
`ScopedPreferenceStore(ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE, "com.example.myplugin.id")`

**Question:**
How can I get Activator's own preference storage qualifier? With other words, how can i create a `ScopedPreferenceStore` which stores the preferences in Activator's own preference storage?

Comment: Are you asking how to get your plugin's preference store without going to the Activator?

Comment: I did not see, that the activator has a static property `PLUGIN_ID` on default. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the equivalent preference store for your bundle without accessing the Activator itself, you would use the same pattern you listed:

```
preferenceStore = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "your.bundle.id");
```

**EDIT:** Finding your bundle id

When eclipse auto-generates your bundle activator, it creates a static field with the bundle id.  But if you don't have an activator, you can still retrieve your bundle id.  You can use `FrameworkUtil` to get the `Bundle` object from any one of your classes.

```
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil;

final Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(PrintIdHandler.class);
System.out.println(bundle.getSymbolicName());
```

Comment: i just searches for a possibility to access the bundleID, without writing it explicetly down. Default Activator generates the field `PLUGIN_ID` which stores the id.